# Сохранение настроек соединения

Tags: сеть, настройки

Доброго времени суток. Дома имеется два компьютера, на одном из них стоит интернет. Недавно приобрел провод(витая пара) для создания локальной сети между компьютерами.

**Проблема** в следующем: каждый раз для установления сети, на компьютере где установлено интернет соединение, приходиться сбрасывать настройки интернета и вводить настройки локальной сети и наоборот.

**Вопрос**: можно ли автоматизировать этот процесс?

**P.S.** Знаю, что в моём случае лучше купить роутер, но всё таки.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, во-первых, для быстрой смены настроек рекомендую вот эту прогу [QuickConfig](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/i_am_advertising/68288/), а во-вторых, может на компе с инетом обзавестись второй сетевой картой и пользоваться инетом и локалкой с обоих компов одновременно?

Comment: ну да. совершенно согласен. что чел себя мучает-то? вопрос всего 120 руб вроде бы